# Regular Expression in Python with re.search ()

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the use of `r` before `"\b` in `re.search(r"\b d\w+", txt)`?

Example:

```
txt = "Wow! it is a Wonderful day"
x = re.search(r"\bW\w+", txt)
print(x.group())
```

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer Don't answer these kinds of questions; find a good target and flag them as duplicates.